# IOs How to add a table view below text field

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am trying to create a list where I want users to enter data in the text view provided above and on they clicking add button it populates in a tableview below. !This is a sample type that I want to create.
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lntkU.png)

Comment: How much code have you written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, the IBAction for the Add button should just add the text entered into the text field into an array that powers the UITableView.  After adding it to an array, call `reloadData` on the UITableView, the UITableView will read the new data, as well as the other data from the NSArray and provide data to the list.